# Merging certain rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe, consisting in 73 rows:

```
Date    Col1    Col2   Col3
1975   float   float  float
1976   float   float  float
1976   float   float  float
1977   float   float  float
1978   float   float  float
....
....
```

There are certain years appearing twice because the values were taken twice that year. What I want to do is to merge those rows where the year is the same, taking the mean value of each column for those specific two rows. The fact is that I am still familiarizing with pandas and I don't really understand the usage of the loc and iloc selectors. This is what I have tried, but I am sure this is completely wrong and non-pythonic:

```
for i in range(72):
    if df.Date[i]==df.Date[i+1]:
        df.Very_satisfied[i]= (df.Very_satisfied[i]+df.Very_satisfied[i+1])/2
        df.Fairly_satisfied[i]= (df.Fairly_satisfied[i]+df.Fairly_satisfied[i+1])/2
        df.NV_satisfied[i]= (df.NV_satisfied[i]+ df.NV_satisfied[i+1])/2
        df.Not_satisfied[i]= (df.Not_satisfied[i]+ df.Not_satisfied[i+1])/2
        df.DK[i]= (df.DK[i]+ df.DK[i+1])/2
        a=i+1
        str(a)
        df.drop(a)
```

where "very satisfied", "fairly satisfied" ecc. are the columns. The point in my code is: if two years are the same calculate the mean of each value, substitute it in the first row and delete the second row.
I really need something smarter and more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) for this. Here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(range(25)) * 2, 'col1': np.random.random(50) * 100, 'col2': np.random.random(50)})
df.groupby('date').mean()
```

This will take all the rows which the same date, calculate the mean value of all the rows in the group for each column.

This outputs on my sample :

```
df.groupby('date').mean().head()
           col1      col2
date
0     42.881950  0.436073
1     32.114299  0.309742
2     96.819446  0.809071
3     30.606661  0.284257
4     40.690211  0.624972
```

For this input :

```
df[df['date'] < 5]

    date       col1      col2
0      0  67.268605  0.393560
1      1  55.864578  0.508636
2      2  97.735942  0.861162
3      3  58.014599  0.117055
4      4   7.429489  0.637101
25     0  18.495296  0.478585
26     1   8.364020  0.110848
27     2  95.902950  0.756980
28     3   3.198724  0.451460
29     4  73.950932  0.612843
```

Comment: I'll never learn... you usually never need more than two lines of code when using python. Thanks a lot for your help mate.